# CircularSpinner Version in Swift 4 or 5 in Xcode 11.4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11.4

Did someone used CircularSpinner for iOS?I used Circular Spinner in Xcode 10.1 with Swift 3 version is oK.

I am facing issued after installing Pod, 
pod 'CircularSpinner'
Error is
[image: Error Pod File is]
Installed version is

[image]

Does I need to add version to fixed this Pod issues?

Comment: Have you added specific version to the pod file for this CircularSpinner?

Comment: No sir,I dont add

Answer (score 0):

Seems the Swift version hasn't been updated for this pod, try installing the Objective-C version and use Bridging Headers that  to access it in Swift

Comment: any reference for that?

Comment: Yes in their documentation: use_frameworks!
pod 'CircularSpinner' , '~> 1.2.0'

Comment: Can share me link?

Comment: https://github.com/taglia3/CircularSpinner/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

pod 'CircularSpinner' only supports upto Swift 3 only. You must find an alternate for this library and my suggestion is

**pod 'UICircularProgressRing'**

Take a look at https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing. I have used this and it is very useful and highly customisable.

Comment: Thanks ,btw no way to use in Swift 4?

Comment: How about PDFReader 2.5.1
SWIFTQRCode  3.0.2,It also same like this one,got Pod error in Xcode 11.4

Comment: To use the same in swift 4, you need to download all library files and make changes according to swift 4 and use it but I guess that is going to be a tedious task. PDFReader 2.5.1 supports swift 4 but SWIFTQRCode 3.0.2 is limited to swift 3.